# PHP Unset acting like a Reference

Tags: php

I am having trouble understanding why PHP is unsetting my `children` property for **both** objects even when I create a copy.

When I assign `$singleNode = $node` it shouldn't remove the singleNode child because I'm not passing a reference, but it's behaving that way.

Can anyone clear this up for me?

**You can run this in PHP CLI to see what I mean**

```
<?php

$node = new stdClass();
$node->title = 'Test';
$node->children = [1,2,3,4,5];


// Does the node have children?
if (property_exists($node, 'children')) {
    echo '$node has children' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '$node NOT has children' . PHP_EOL;
}

// Assign node to a new variable, and remove children
$singleNode = $node;
if (property_exists($singleNode, 'children')) {
    echo '$singleNode removed children' . PHP_EOL;
    unset($singleNode->children);
}


// Does the node have children?
if (property_exists($node, 'children')) {
    echo '$node has children' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '$node NOT has children' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I found I can do this:

`$singleNode = clone $node`

Is that the right way to do this? Why does this happen? No matter what I assign the variable to, the variable is referencing the same item in memory?

Comment: working code: http://codepad.org/iInMQ6o9 - it is just @JREAM code - not solution :)

Comment: Well the $node should still have children.

Comment: Have a look at the [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) docs.

Comment: This is a natural error to make, because normally PHP requires you explicitly define a reference with it's handy & character. However, objects work differently and they are effectively references by default.

Comment: Well said BrianDHall, I think thats why I was thrown for a loop :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having just one object. To get a second object you would have to create a `clone`. Technically `$singleNode = $node` is copying the oject handle which still refers to the same object.

See 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: Man I cant believe Ive never run into this problem after all these years, I guess that is the case. Thanks for confirming with link +1 and +green check once I am allowed to :)

Comment: If "after all these years" goes back to PHP 4 then the behavior was different :)

Comment: I cant believe how stupid I feel, its so obvious why it works this way. Im not creating a new Instance.